# How to display the output and also save it in global temp table in ms-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Usually when we use select statement it displays the output, but when insert into is used,stores the result into temp table.i want to do both.Display result and store in temp table as well in dynamic sql.

```
        IF @DisplayInSelect IS NOT NULL
            SET @DisplayInSelect = ','+@DisplayInSelect     
        SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT  a.'+@column_name+' FROM ['+@TableName+'] a where '+@FullCondition+' )'+
                    'SELECT DISTINCT ''Error at column: '+@Column_name+''' as [Error Records if found any are shown below],'''+ISNULL(@CustomErrorMessage,'ERROR')+''''+ISNULL(@DisplayInSELECT,'')+', a.'+@column_name+',* FROM ['+@TableName+'] a where '+@FullCondition+'

                    INSERT INTO ##error_check(SELECT DISTINCT ''Error at column: '+@Column_name+''' as [Error Records if found any are shown below],'''+ISNULL(@CustomErrorMessage,'ERROR')+''''+ISNULL(@DisplayInSELECT,'')+', a.'+@column_name+', *FROM ['+@TableName+'] a where '+@FullCondition+');

        PRINT('IQR1 sql is'+@SQL)
        EXEC(@SQL) 

     END
```

Comment: I don't really get the relevance of the code sample. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use insert into table along with Exec. Try like this,

```
IF @DisplayInSelect IS NOT NULL
    SET @DisplayInSelect = ',' + @DisplayInSelect
SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT  a.' + @column_name + ' FROM [' + @TableName + '] a where ' + @FullCondition + ' )' + 'SELECT DISTINCT ''Error at column: ' + @Column_name + ''' as [Error Records if found any are shown below],''' + ISNULL(@CustomErrorMessage, 'ERROR') + '''' + ISNULL(@DisplayInSELECT, '') + ', a.' + @column_name + ',* FROM [' + @TableName + '] a where ' + @FullCondition + '
     SELECT DISTINCT ''Error at column: ' + @Column_name + ''' as [Error Records if found any are shown below],''' + ISNULL(@CustomErrorMessage, 'ERROR') + '''' + ISNULL(@DisplayInSELECT, '') + ', a.' + @column_name + ', *FROM [' + @TableName + '] a where ' + @FullCondition + ';'
--To Save
INSERT INTO ##error_check
EXEC (@SQL)

PRINT (' IQR1 sql IS ' + @SQL)
--To Display
EXEC (@SQL)
```